# count cannot be resolved to variable in Eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomBarChart2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        int barNumber;
        int [] barLength = new int[10];
        char [] barSymbols = new char[10];

        System.out.println("How many bars would you like to display:");
        barNumber = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Specify the sizes of the bars:");

        for (int count = 0; count < barNumber; count++)
        {
            barLength [count] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Specify the symbols to be used for the bars:");

        for (int count = 0; count < barNumber; count++)
        {
            barSymbols [count] = scan.next(".").charAt(0);
            System.out.print((count+1)+" ");

            /*for (int length = 0; length < barLength [count]; length++)
            {
                System.out.print(barSymbols [count]);
            }*/

            System.out.println();
        }

        barprint();
        scan.close();

    }

    static void barprint(int[] barLength, char[] barSymbols) 
    {
        for (int length = 0; length < barLength [count]; length++)
        {
            System.out.print(barSymbols [count]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I have so far. Under the method barprint, Eclipse is warning of an error stating that count cannot be resolved to variable. Please help, thanks! Have not programmes before and have no clue where the error is!

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow Please refer this [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show the complete class code. Is count a class member? Where is it defined? Is it static?

Comment: Have you initialized the variable count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling barprint method properly . it takes two arguments.
Replace

```
barprint();
```

with

```
barprint( barLength, barSymbols);
```

and change you method implementation to

```
static void barprint(int[] barLength, char[] barSymbols) 
{
    for (int length = 0; length < barLength.length; length++)
    {
        System.out.print(barLength[length]);
    }

    for (int length = 0; length < barSymbols.length; length++)
    {
        System.out.print(barSymbols [length]);
    }
}
```

when you take input from user ensure that barlength size and barSymbol size cannot be more than 10 . If it is more than 10 your program will be crashed beacuse  in strat you defined thier size , which is 10.

```
int [] barLength = new int[10];
char [] barSymbols = new char[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

please pass barLength and  barSysmbols to the method barprint().
You have not initialized count variable in barprint method(). Without initialized, you can't get. Eclipse doesn't know what the count is here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that method `barprint` doesn't know what is `count`. Furthermore, the syntax you used in `for` loop is incorrect. The way to write this method is:

```
static void barprint(int[] barLength, char[] barSymbols) {
    for (int index = 0; index < barLength.length; index++) {
        System.out.print(barSymbols[index]);
    }
}
```